# Error cross domain call using WCF Rest

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

I'm trying to make a WCF service with CORS calls, so far, I have my server with the classes indicated here: http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html

I was able to make a call with a jQuery ajax call using the verb GET without any parameters, the problem comes when I try to pass parameters to my request, here's my code:

**Interface markup:**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "*",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
string GetData(TestClass value);
```

**Method markup:**

```
public string GetData(TestClass value)
{
     return value.Id.ToString();
}
```

**js markup:**

```
var value = { 
    Id : "2", 
    Name: "qwe" 
};

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:38733/Service1.svc/GetData",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ value: value }),
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

But if I debug, I always get null, meaning that the parameter is not being passes to the method, I also got `POST http://localhost:38733/Service1.svc/GetData 400 (Bad Request)` on Chrome console.

What am I doing wrong?

> UPDATE

**Web.config markup:**

```
<behavior name="jsonBehavior">
    <webHttp />
    <crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior />
</behavior>

<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior" 
         type="WCFSecureService.EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior, WCFSecureService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>

<services>
  <service name="WCFSecureService.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="webHttpBinding" 
              behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" 
              contract="WCFSecureService.IService1" />
  </service>
</services>
```

On the Google Chrome Console I'm getting the following:

`OPTIONS http://localhost:38733/Service1.svc/GetData?value=5`

> UPDATE

It works if I make a request to a method without any parameters

> UPDATE

Fiddler 2 is showing me this, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

[image: request error]

> UPDATE

**TestClass markup:**

```
[DataContract]
public class TestClass
{
    private int id;
    private string name;

    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }        
}
```

> UPDATE

If I use `JSON.stringify({ value: value })` and `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` I reach the server, but I got all properties with 0, check the next image:

[image: error on debug]

Comment: Try removing double quote from your data {"value":5}

Comment: Just post your value, not {value:value} and show the code for your TestClass

Comment: @Strelok I've updated my question with the `TestClass` markup. I just used `data: JSON.stringify({ value })`, but I'm still getting 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: @user123456 you're very close. Just `data: JSON.stringify(value)`

Comment: @user123456 and change to WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare. Check out this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/722874/Post-JSON-data-to-WCF-RESTful-Service-using-jQuery

Comment: @Strelok ok, we're advancing, I can reach the server but the object `value` is now null, and fiddler now shows `{"Id":"2","Name":"qwe"}` instead of `{"value":{"Id":"2","Name":"qwe"}}`. This is a nightmare...

Comment: Yes change to WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare and read that tutorial I linked.

Comment: @Strelok I'm looking at it, and I changed to `Bare`. if I use `JSON.stringify(value)` I get a **400: Bad Request**, if I use `JSON.stringify({ value: value })` I got the object but with all the properties on 0. I have updated my question so you can see it. Any ideas? =(

Comment: @Strelok I just realized that I can't use `Bare` if I'm gonna pass more that one parameter, WCF says that the request needs to be wrapped. I'm doomed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service contract you might want to put an optional `WebGet` directive.

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetData/{value}")]
string GetData(int value);
```

Another thing to look for is that you have a `json` behavior defined for your enpoint in the web.config.

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
        <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="xmlBehavior">
      <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml"/>
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

NOTE: If you are using behaviors and then you need to specify the format in the following manner

```
http://localhost:38733/Service1.svc/json/GetData/5
```

or

```
http://localhost:38733/Service1.svc/xml/GetData/5
```

Also, could you try this js instead:

```
var _data= {
    value:5
};

$.ajax({
    ...
    data: _data,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

Or conversely:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:38733/Service1.svc/json/GetData/5",
});
```

Comment: But with `WebGet` I will not be able to use other methods like `POST`. `js` changes are not working either. I have updated my answer with the behavior of my `web.config`. Thanks!

Comment: If I try using `UriTemplate` on `WebGet` I get the followin error: `Operation 'GetData' in contract 'IService1' has a path variable named 'value' which does not have type 'string'`

Comment: There are many ways to package, envelope, transport, serialize, de-serialize in wcf. You have to find the combination that works for your api. Sorry I was not much of assistance.

Comment: Don't worry, thx for helping, if you have any other idea, feel free to tell it, I'm kinda frustrated with this error.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution for my case. At the end this was a test, so I'm gonna be using more that just one parameter so this is what I've learn:

- For more than one parameter, the request has to be wrapped, so, the
  annotation of the contract for `WebInvoke` has to be `BodyStyle =
  WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest`.
- On the client side, for just one parameter, using `JSON.stringify(value)` it's ok, but for more than one, you have to be more specific, for example:

  ```
  data: JSON.stringify({
      value: value, 
      text: "any text"
  });
  ```
- On the link I provide on my question, I have to included two clases
  `CustomHeaderMessageInspector` and
  `EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior`, it seems that they are
  not longer needed if you can make use of a **global.asax** file, you
  just have to add the following code to **Application_BeginRequest**:

  ```
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
  {
      HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE, GET");

      HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
      HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
      HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
  }
  ```

And my `web.config` end it up like this:

```
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="corsBinding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service name="WCFSecureService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="bs" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFSecureService.IService1" />
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="corsBinding"
              behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
              contract="WCFSecureService.IService1" />
  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>        
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Thanks for your helps and I hope it helps someone else out there.